# First five digits of a googol factorial

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, number-theory

<sub>Based off of: [MacPOW 1134](https://stanwagon.com/potw/fall10/p1134.html)</sub>

Without using a calculator/computer, can you determine the first five digits of $10^{100}!$ (a googol factorial)?

I came up with this when trying to solve the question this is based off of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> no.

So, Stirling's formula says that $n!\simeq\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}(n/e)^n$, so the answer we're looking for almost certainly agrees with the first five digits of the RHS.

The $1/\sqrt n$ bit gives a factor of $10^{-50}$ which doesn't affect the first (any number of) digits. The $n^n$ bit gives a factor of $10^{-\text{somethinglarge}}$, ditto. So we want the first few significant digits of $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi n}}\times\exp(-\text{googol})$.

It feels marginally easier to look at the reciprocal: $\sqrt{2\pi} \exp(\text{googol})$. Multiplication is easy (I guess we're allowed *calculators*, but if necessary it can be done by hand). So what we now need is a good way to estimate the early digits of $\exp(\text{googol})$.

Well, $10^x=\exp(x\log10)$ so $10^{(\text{googol}/\log 10)}=\exp(\text{googol})$. So what we need is the fractional part of $\text{googol}/\log(10)$. (This goes both ways: if we have a good estimate for the early digits of $\exp(\text{googol})$ then that gives us a good estimate of the fractional part of $\text{googol}/\log 10$.)

But now we have a difficulty: this is essentially the same thing as knowing about 100 digits of $1/\log(10)$. So the question is roughly equivalent to "what are the 100th to 104th significant digits of $1/\log(10)$?". (It might be the 101th to 105th or something. But something along those lines.) And I am fairly sure there isn't a good way to do that without a computer.

(The question that's the inspiration for this one is much more doable by hand.)

Comment: How does one answer the inspiration question?

Comment: @Someone:  the rightmost many digits of any large factorial are $0$.  In fact, about the rightmost $\frac n4$ digits of $n!$ are $0$.  There are lots of factors of $2$, and $\frac 15$ of the numbers have a factor $5$.  The numbers with more factors of $5$ raise it to almost $\frac 14$

Comment: Yes, but the question is about the rightmost _nonzero_ digit.

Comment: @Someone The rightmost nonzero digit is obviously even, so we just need to know what it is mod 5. Now split up the numbers 1..N, whose product is N!, into the multiples of 5 -- which yield a power of 5 times floor(N/5)! -- and the others -- which behave in a nice periodic way. This lets you compute the last nonzero digit of N! with little effort if you can compute the last nonzero digit of floor(N/5)!. Now recurse.